# Is there an official Miraculous episode order?

Tags: chronological-order, miraculous-ladybug

The episode order of *Miraculous: Tales of Ladybug and Cat Noir*, season 3 in particular, is a convoluted mess.  [No](https://miraculousladybug.fandom.com/wiki/Season_3) [two](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2580046/episodes) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Miraculous:_Tales_of_Ladybug_%26_Cat_Noir_episodes) seem to give the same one, so I'm not sure which to believe.

I understand that *Miraculous* episodes are released to different countries on different dates and, for some reason, occasionally in a different order.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLq-B55Nv6w) even claims that episodes aren't always finished in chronological order, and the production company is less than strict about keeping them together (the events of "Ikari Gozen" take place after the most recently released episode, "Feast").

Is there an official chronological order for these?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/miraculousladybug/comments/cwswdw/list_of_season_13_episodes_in_production_code/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The production order (and 'production code' for each episode) has been confirmed by the [official Miraculous (Latin America) twitter channel](https://twitter.com/MiraculousMX/status/1091484996383227905).

> I have been sent these screencaps a lot, and yes, they are REAL. The Swiss RTS DEUX chain has uploaded all the short synopses of Miraculous season 3 (bye many hahah surprises!) to its page.
>
> <sub><sup>[Per twitter - MiracleMexico](https://twitter.com/MiraculousMX/status/1091484996383227905)</sup></sub>

You can find the English translations of the episode names [here](https://miraculousladybug.fandom.com/wiki/Season_3#cite_note-:MLBS3_RTS_FRCH-15).

[image]